# rkhunter warnings about a script and a hidden directory

Tags: debian, security, rkhunter

When I run a scan with `rkhunter` I get 2 warnings. I checked the log file and warnings are as the following:

```
Warning: The command '/usr/bin/unhide.rb' has been replaced by a script: /usr/bin/unhide.rb: Ruby script, ASCII te$

[15:05:43]   Checking for hidden files and directories       [ Warning ]
[15:05:43] Warning: Hidden directory found: '/etc/.java'
```

What I should do to correct these problems? My OS is Debian wheezy 7.1.

Comment: I don't see anything that needs to be corrected.

Comment: what about warnings ?

Comment: @ekaj it's a long time since I posted this, and If I still remember, I didn't anything, because it seems that it wasn't a security problem but just a warning as mentioned in the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These look fairly benign, and you can probably just ignore them. Rkhunter and chkrootkit are very blunt tools, and they tend to give lots of false warnings.